# Why loading dll file from embedded resource is not working?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

In the past, I used to dynamically load the file `System.Data.SQLite.dll` by calling this in the main method :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string resource1 = "System.Data.SQLite.dll"; // 
            string resource2 = "Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll";

            EmbeddedAssembly.Load(resource1, "System.Data.SQLite.dll");
            EmbeddedAssembly.Load(resource2, "Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll");
             //
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        }
        catch (Exception E) { File.AppendAllText("myExcept.txt",E.Message); }
    }




  static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        return EmbeddedAssembly.Get(args.Name);
    }
```

Where EmbeddedAssembly.cs is a class that I have found on [this link in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)

I have already used this method before and it worked for me, but now I need to compile a cs file dynamically from c# code : So I added the file `System.Data.SQLite.dll` as an embedded resource and as a referencedassembly, something like this :

```
            ...

            String exeName = "myFile.exe"

            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");

            // add reference 
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.SQLite.dll");

            // add embedded resources
            cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(@"System.Data.SQLite.dll");

            ...
```

But after generating the executable file It still depends on `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file, so if I do not put this file in the same folder with the Exe, the file won't work !

The other thing that Confused me is that the file Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll is loaded correctly whereas `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is throwing an exception :

`Cannot load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.86.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The specified file cannot be found`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you load the assemblies manually. You can do this by referencing them in your project file?

As an alternative SQLite has nuget package. Using this is very handy on loading an assembly for AnyCPU/x86 or x64).

Comment: I'm doing this because I'm compiling the executable file programmatically out of a cs file.

Comment: Can you describe this a little bit more detailed?

Comment: The dll file `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is required by a .CS file that is compiled from within code in another application (using CodeProvider), and thus, I cannot use the IDE to add the reference manually, I'm searching for a solution that let me reference the dll file programatically, add it as embedded resource and load it dynamically on the application start-up as it is described in the link I attached in the question. But this solution worked only for one dll file (Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll) but doesn't worked for `System.Data.SQLite.dll`. I get the exceotion above.

Comment: May be a silly question, but did you check the version number: Version=1.0.86.0?

Comment: Yes, the version number is the same. Inside the IDE I have to specify x86 in the configuration manager instead of Any CPU. How can I do it programatically ?